# C++ make::shared wrapping on existing raw pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am working on a small wrapper for an FMOD library. Below is a snippet of the code that I have, and there are other libraries that manage the `SoundData` class:

```
class SoundData
{
public: 
    ...
    std::string mSoundName;
    std::shared_ptr<FMOD::Sound> mFmodSoundHandle;
    ...
}

void SoundLib::CreateSound(SoundData& data)
{
    FMOD::Sound *sound = nullptr;
    system->createSound(data.mSoundName.data(), FMOD_DEFAULT, nullptr, &sound);
    data.mFmodSoundHandle = std::make_shared<FMOD::Sound>(sound);
}
```

Trying to compile this snippet of the code, I get this error:

> Error C2664   'FMOD::Sound::Sound(const FMOD::Sound &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'FMOD::Sound *' to 'const FMOD::Sound &'  SoundLib    ...\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xutility   158

I cannot quite understand if I am using `std::make_shared()` in the wrong way here? The goal here is to save the output from `createSound()` that is passed as a `sound` variable into the structure `SoundData`. Variable data will be managed afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a pointer where you should pass a reference. Try `*sound`.

Notice that you're not wrapping a pointer, you're creating a new instance of `Sound` and copying the value of `*sound` into it.

To wrap it consider:

```
data.mFmodSoundHandle.reset(sound);
```

Comment: Oh, I figured out what is not working. That actually helps with what you said, constructor for creating a new Sound from FMOD is private thus I am trying to do something that is not possible. Instead, I thought I have something else messed up. Thanks, My design for this feature was wrong from the begging, will have to change it.